Paranormal alien spider island that a pilot crashed onto
Country of origin: USA, I guess
Year: 80s or 90s
Title: Something like "something the third", maybe beast 3, creature 3 or something.
Plot:
Movie starts with a space scene, there is an alien with his personal spacecraft. The spacecraft malfunctions, he tries but can't fix it. Then he crashed to earth.
In some scene I guess the body of the alien is shown when he is dying.
A jet fighter pilot, when passing over the tropical island that alien crashed, also malfunctions and he crashes too. Years after that, maybe 10 years, his sister came to find her brother. I guess she is also a fighter pilot.
There is a rescue team or something like that. And there are huge spiders on that island. Poisonous spiders paralyzing some of the team members and planting eggs inside them. And wrapping them with spider silk.
Finally, the woman pilot finds her brother's skeleton hanging from a tree.
There are some paranormal things at this island. It seems like this island is a Bermuda triangle island.
Characters:
Woman pilot wearing a green pilot uniform and she got dark hair and she is white. Also her brother got dark hair, I guess.
There is a white team member wearing glasses and he does not survive; he is caught by a spider in front of the other team members. In further scenes he's got pale skin because he is paralyzed, to feed the spider eggs. He is I guess a spider enthusiast scientist so he let the other mates leave him. He says something like, "If you rescue me, I die. Let me be paralyzed so the baby spiders can benefit from me".

Kindly work on your formatting, you can refer the edits submitted on your question for it.

Sounds like Arachnid from 2001 about an island full of giant spiders.

A plane crashes on an island, and the pilot comes across a giant spider, which kills both him and an alien. One year later, Mercer (Alex Reid), the sister of the pilot, accompanies Valentine (Chris Potter) to the same island to locate her brother.

There's no 3 in the title AFAIK, but it was called 8 Legs in Finland. Here's the trailer:




You beat me. :)

@casspir Whoops! Sorry. :S

thank you again for finding my movie again. @casspir you guys are so fast i didnt think somebody will answer that fast, thank you for your response. this is the movie im loking for. but i cant find my described opening scene, an alien crashes to earth. but this movie starts with fighter crash. if it was from another movie then i will ask it at another question.
